# Angular, WebAPI, and CORS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am running a web application with angular that needs to call a separate ASP.NET Web API application to retrieve data. They are both running on different ports: (web server) *44302*, and (web api server) *44307*. I understand that to do this, **CORS needs to be enabled on the web API server, which I have done my best to set up correctly**:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and on the ApiController:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:44302", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ClientController : ApiController
    {

    // GET: Client
    public IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Additionally, I have added this to angular:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

Unfortunately, a simple API call from angular still returns a 404 error..

```
this.getClients = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/client');
    }
```

When entering *localhost:44307/api/client* into the browser, everything works as expected. What am I missing? I've searched tutorial upon tutorial to find something I'm not doing correctly, but it seems like I've included everything.

Comment: The 404 error you're receiving means that the resource you're calling cannot be found. This has nothing to do with CORS and enabling access.  If had to do with that you'd see a 400(Bad Request) error as well as 'Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' The first thing I'd do is try and access the endpoint and get a response through a client like 'Postman'.  Once you have established that endpoint is working through there you can then move to the client-side code(angular) and implement there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Enable CORS as you mentioned.

Do it as follows:

At the Global.asax, add the following method to configure CORS:

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

and it's done!